On the proof of building an SKE from a PRF
I am reading the construction that we make a SKE scheme $\sf \Pi=(Gen,Enc,Dec)$ from a PRF $F$. In particular, work on the proof there we assume that given a secure PRF, we can construct a CPA-secure symmetric key encryption scheme (SKE).
Part of the proof is the following.
Let $F: \Bbb Z_2^n \times \Bbb  Z_2^\ell \longrightarrow \Bbb Z_2^m$ be a PRF.
Let us assume that we have the following two Games (Experiments):



Game $\sf{Left}'$
Game $\sf{Left}''$




INIT($1^n$):
INIT($1^n$):


$k \gets \sf Gen(1^n)$
$k \gets \sf Gen(1^n)$


Oracle LR($m_L$):
Oracle LR($m_L$):


$r \gets \Bbb Z_2^\ell$
$r,r' \gets \Bbb Z_2^\ell$


$y\gets F_k(r) \oplus m_L$
$y \gets r'\oplus m_L$


Return $c:=(r,y:=F_k(r)\oplus m_L)$
Return $c:=(r,r' \oplus m_L)$



We also consider the following two Games:

Question: Given a adversary $B$ against the Left Games making $q$ (distinct) oracle queries, can we construct a adversary A against $\cal{L}_\sf{samp}$ games, making $q$ oracle queries such that
$${\sf{Adv}^{Left}}(B) = {\sf{Adv}^{{\cal L}_\sf{samp}}}(A)\leq q^2/2^\ell?$$
Can we directly show that ${\sf{Adv}^{Left}}(B) \leq q^2/2^\ell$?
References:

The Joy of Cryptography, M. Rosulek, p. 80
MIT 6.875, Lecture 4, 2023.


The Joy of Cryptography has a full security proof of this construction on p136. It proves real-vs-random (not left-vs-right) security, and it is not explicitly written in terms of concrete security (advantage functions), but it would be easy to adapt in those ways.

Thanks for your answer, the textbook is excellent and indeed provides a clear proog. I was just trying to combine more than one sources, but the result is not satisfying...

Can you expand the acronym SKE for readability

@kodlu Yes, of course
